# Hausdorff dimension of an algebraic variety

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, projective-varieties

I have the following elementary question that I cannot quite figure out myself or find an appropriate reference:

Let $p$ be a nonzero homogeneous polynomial which we view as a function on $\mathbb R^n$. Let $S^{n-1}$ denote the unit sphere $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\colon |x|=1\}$. Prove that
$$
\mathcal H^{n-2}(\{x\in S^{n-1}\colon p(x)=0\})<\infty.
$$
Here $\mathcal H^d$ denotes the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

A couple of remarks: I expect a bound only in terms of the degree of $p$ and probably space dimension $n$, but I would be happy with a bound that depends on $p$ in any way. This speculation is clear if $n=2$, when $\mathcal H^{0}(\{x\in S^{n-1}\colon p(x)=0\})\leq 2\mathrm{deg\,}p$. I tried to find some sort of argument involving slicing and/or (co)area formula, but I could not make it work.

Thank you!

Comment: Every algebraic subset is a union of finitely many smooth submanifolds (of different dimension in general).

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I don't dispute the triviality of the statement, but I would be super happy to have an argument for the fact that $\mathcal H^{d-2}(\{x\in S^{n-1}\colon p(x)=0\})\leq C(n,\mathrm{deg\,}p)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645858/upper-bound-on-surface-area-of-algebraic-surfaces/677667#677667

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!